# Accessing Cratedb via HTTP Endoint vs PostgreSQL Wire Protocol

Tags: http, npgsql, crate, cratedb

I was wondering if anyone has tried comparing the speed in querying (lets just say any arbitrary query for this exercise) using either HTTP end point and the PostgreSQL connection to cratedb.

Considering what's under the hood is elastic search (lucene) engine which is HTTP based and Crate having its Postgresql spin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reached out to CrateIO and Peter from CrateIO confirmed that using HTTP would be faster than using PostrgreSQL

Comment: By PostgreSQL, do you mean JDBC inserts ? I am reading this as JDBC inserts are slower than insertion via HTTP end point. Is this correct understanding? Do you have any idea of comparison of speed of HTTP end point and "Copy From" command ?

Comment: @vinayakshukre not quite, I was using datareader (C#) via the 5432 port, I did conduct comparison and it seemed that while the actual query seemed to perform better using datareader option the opening of the connection and time it took outperformed HTTP method. (once you issued 2nd HTTP call it was quicker than traditional sql connection).